# Laravel storage image on server is not showing

Tags: laravel, laravel-storage

Hello laravel storage link image is showing perfectly in localhost and when i upload the project to shared hosting images are broken. To show images i have been using this syntax

```
<img src="/storage/users_image/{{$user->users_image }}"
```

the above one works great on localhost on shared hosting this images are broken to solve i make storage link but images are broken again on broken images it shows `https://www.yuvxyz.com/storage/users_image/xxxy.png`
note i have uploaded public and other folders on different folders.

Comment: `php artisan storage:link` will solve the issue

Comment: @sta i have make the command itsnot working

Comment: delete and make again

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution from YouTube and it works i have created symlink then it worked here is the PHP file